# how we can provide one column placed in two combination of unique constraints in entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, entity, unique-constraint

@Table(name = "context", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(name = "uniqueNameAndCompanyUid", columnNames = { "name", "company_uid" }),
@UniqueConstraint(name = "uniqueNameAndStatus", columnNames = { "name", "is_deleted" }) })

Comment: above line im added in entity but doen't work

Comment: Hi, is it throwing any error